# PDE and Volterra Equation: the role of boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, integral-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have to deal with the following PDE which describes the evolution of the generating function $\mathcal{Z}(h,t)$ for a population of cells dividing with rate $\gamma$:
$$
\partial_t\mathcal{Z}(h,t)=\gamma(h^2-h)\partial_h\mathcal{Z}(h,t)
$$
where the initial condition is given by $\mathcal{Z}(h,t=0)=h$.\

Bellman and Harris showed also that the following integral equation holds for such generating function:
$$
\mathcal{Z}(h,t)=e^{-\gamma t}h+\int_0^t\mathcal{Z}^2(h,t-x)e^{-\gamma x}dx
$$
**I need to use the Characteristic curvers method to convert the PDE into the previous Integral non linear Volterra equation**\

*I know that such PDE can be solved exactly but it is not my goal*

The characteristic curves system is given by:
$$
\dot{t}(s,\tau)=1\\
\dot{h}(s,\tau)=-\gamma (h^2-h)\\
\dot{\mathcal{Z}}=0
$$
The second ODE can be cast as:
$$
\dot{h}(s,\tau)=-\gamma (h^2-h)\\
\frac{d}{ds}\big(e^{-\gamma s}h(s,\tau)\big)=-\gamma h^2(s,\tau)e^{-\gamma s}\\
e^{-\gamma s}h(s,\tau)-h(0,\tau)=-\int_0^s\gamma h^2(u,\tau)e^{-\gamma u}du\\
h(0,\tau)=e^{-\gamma s}h(s,\tau)+\int_0^s\gamma h^2(u,\tau)e^{-\gamma u}du\\
$$
Because of the fact that the generating functional is constant along the Characteristic curves:
$$
\dot{\mathcal{Z}}=0\rightarrow \mathcal{Z}(h(s,\tau),t(s,\tau))=\mathcal{Z}(h(0,\tau),t(0,\tau))=h(0,\tau)
$$
and also:
$$
t(s,\tau)=s\rightarrow t(0,\tau)=0
$$
Then:
$$
\mathcal{Z}(h(s,\tau),t(s,\tau))=e^{-\gamma s}h(s,\tau)+\int_0^s\gamma h^2(u,\tau)e^{-\gamma u}du\\
\mathcal{Z}(h,t)=e^{-\gamma t}h+\int_0^t\gamma h^2(u,\tau)e^{-\gamma u}du\\
$$
Furthermore, comparing the two equations:
$$
\mathcal{Z}(h,t)=e^{-\gamma t}h+\int_0^t\gamma \color{red}{h^2(u,\tau)}e^{-\gamma u}du\\
\mathcal{Z}(h,t)=e^{-\gamma t}h+\int_0^t\gamma \color{red}{\mathcal{Z}^2(h,t-u)}e^{-\gamma u}du
$$
**My question is: why I can say that $h(s,t)=\mathcal{Z}(h,t-s)$???**\

**I know that we can prove such relation solving the PDE exactly but I need to understand why such relation holds without using the exact solution **